# Code not highlighted on github pages markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I created a github page, using [jekyll's minimal theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal)

I'm writing the pages in markdown. In my _config.yml file, I have the options :

```yaml
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
    input: GFM
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

Somehow, the code is however not highlighted : https://sergedmi.github.io/pages/arccos

Note that the minimal theme does contain a [css stylesheet](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/blob/master/_sass/rouge-github.scss) that should highlight the code according to rouge markup.

The code is correctly highlighted in github : https://github.com/SergeDmi/SergeDmi.github.io/blob/master/pages/arccos.md

Any tip ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated Answer

I am confident that the fix is to change `C++` to `cpp` in your Markdown code blocks.

### Here is how I tested the fix.

1. `jekyll new cpp-test`
2. Add the configuration to the auto-generated `_config.yml` to use `rouge` for code block syntax highlighting.

```
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
    input: GFM
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

3. Run `jekyll s` in new `cpp-test` directory

### Rendering

Here is what it looks like with `C++`
[image: C++ example]

Here is what it looks like with `cpp`
[image: ccp example]

## Original Answer

Could it be that you need to use `cpp` instead of `C++` in your Markdown code blocks?

It looks like GitHub will syntax highlight your code blocks the same if you switch `C++` to `cpp`.

Rouge documents C++ as `cpp` here https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/blob/master/docs/Languages.md.